# comparing two colums and printing a new file using awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have two files with 4 columns each. I am trying to compare the second column from the first file with the second column from the second file. I have managed to check on some websites how to do it, and it works, but I have a problem printing a new file containing the whole second file and 3rd and 4nd column from the first file. I have tried to use such a syntax:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{label[$2]=$2;date[$2]=$3;date[$2]=$4;next}; ($2==label[$2]){print $0"   "date[$2]}' file1 file2
```

I was only able to add the 4th column from the first file. Where do I make a mistake?

Comment: Good that you have shown samples in your question, please do add samples of input and expected output too in your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following, since no samples are given so not tested it.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{label[$2]=$2;date[$2]=$3;date[$2]=$3 OFS $4;next}; ($2==label[$2]){print $0"   "date[$2]}' file1 file2
```

Basically you need to change from `date[$2]=$4` TO `date[$2]=$3 OFS $4` to get both 3rd and 4th field in the output.